# I can not see utf-8 strings on django powered by tornado server

Tags: django, utf-8, tornado

I have a django server running on tornado server.

When I use special caracters like ó or ñ the page certain part of a certain django template is not rendered (character set has been especified to 'utf-8' in settings.py and tornado_script.py # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-).

Considering that just a certain part of the template is not well rendered (a form) and the server works perfectly using the django built-in runserver, I could supposed the problem is comming from tornado server, but I can not debug that configuration.

If some of you know how to debug this to find the missing configuration, please let me know.

I've been searching a lot last 3 hours with no results.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Probably your browser is guessing the character set wrong. Some browsers allow you to set the encoding, I would suggest trying setting it to UTF-8. If this is indeed the problem, you can set the encoding as a meta tag so all browsers will always pick the right encoding. Add this to `head`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

You should also make sure that your special characters are really in UTF-8. Most editors allows you to enforce this. You can also set a special encoding for your Python files, which will choke if anything else appears. Add the following to the beginning of your Pytho source with weird characters:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Comment: The problem is that using python manage.py runserver works perfectly but using tornado dont.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the tornado "render" for templates likes to do its own encoding which may be messing things up for you.

you can look at their [source code](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler) to see exactly what it does...

Try using "write" instead and see whether the characters appear in the output, then you may have a better idea of what's happening.

J